# Performance of setting parameters of an object in Rust

Tags: struct, constructor, rust, instantiation

I have been wondering about different ways of instantiating structs I came across in Rust so far. So there is the most basic/simple way of setting all the fields manually when everything is public:

```
let a = Structure { arg1: T, arg2: T, ... }
```

When there is a need for privacy and better interface and/or defaults, it's common to use 'contructors' such us new(), etc:

```
let a = Structure::new(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Now, so far it kind of makes sens to me. However there seems to be a third common way of doing the same which confuses me the most. Here is a concrete example:

```
let mut image_file = OpenOptions::new()
                        .write(true)
                        .truncate(true)
                        .create(true)
                        .open(file_path)
                        .unwrap();
```

So my questions are:

1. What are the performance impact of these different solutions ( if any )?
2. What are general benefits and disadvantages of each?
3. Are there more ways of doing the same?
4. Which is the best practice?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't quite match the content; you are asking many more questions than originally stated.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yeah, you are right. Looks like because of this the question was put on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have identified 3 ways to create a `struct`:

1. Direct: directly initializing its fields,
2. Constructor: calling a single function which initializes the `struct`,
3. Builder: assembling the `struct` elements piece-meal then finally initializing a `struct`.

> Are there more ways of doing the same?

Direct initialization has two variations: either initialing each field directly, or initializing a few fields and "defaulting" the others with `struct S { f0, .. OTHERS }` where `OTHERS` is an instance of `S`.

The Constructor and Builder ways have a exponential number of variations, depending on how you group the parameters, and in some instances the line between the two will be blurry.

All ways, however, must at some point converge and use (1) to create an instance of `S`.

> What are general benefits and disadvantages of each?

This is... irrelevant, to some extent.

Each of the 3 alternatives caters to a different set of needs:

- Direct initialization requires accessible fields; since `pub` fields are rare it is therefore mostly used within the crate but not usable by clients.
- Constructor and Builder allow establishing invariants and are therefore the primary client's interface.

The Constructor is simple but inflexible: no new parameter can be added without breaking backward compatibility (another Constructor can, of course); the Builder on the other hand is flexible, at the cost of verbosity.

> What are the performance impact of these different solutions ( if any )?

Ideally, in an optimized binary, both Constructor and Builder should have the same cost. If it matters, profile.

Direct initialization will be faster than either if they establish invariants, as it does not. Comparing the performance of non-equivalent functionality rarely matters though.

> Which is the best practice?

Avoid Direct Initialization.

Direct Initialization does NOT establish invariants, it's up to the surrounding code to establishing them, which therefore means that any time Direct Initialization is used the invariant checking code is duplicated, which violates the DRY principle.

Direct Initialization also goes against encapsulation, preventing any further change of the underlying structure, down to the type of the fields used. This is generally undesirable.

There are exceptions, as always. The most prominent being that implementing the Constructor or Builder requires using Direct Initialization down the road.

Choosing between Constructor and Builder is more subjective. In general, I recommend a Constructor when the parameters are few, even if this means writing a few of them, such as `Vec::{new, with_capacity}`. When the number of Constructors would get out of hand if one needed to write one for each combination of parameters which makes sense, then use a Builder instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthieu! This clarifies things quite a lot, the only thing I am not sure if I understand is the part about direct initialization and the invariants and encapsulation.

Comment: @dawid: Imagine `struct Even { number: i64 }`. The *contract* (also known as invariant, for it never varies) is that its `number` field is always even. If anyone can direct initialize it (if `number` is `pub`), then sooner or later someone will write `Even { number: 3 }`. *Oops*. Therefore, you should have a constructor `fn new(n: i64) -> Option<Even>` which returns `Some(Even { number: n })` if `n` is even, and `None` otherwise, thus *establishing the invariant* that `Even::number` is always even.